# Predicate-Polymorphic Modules in Alloy?

Tags: module, polymorphism, alloy

In alloy you can make modules polymorphic on signatures by defining them as arguments in the module definition, e.g.:

```
module mymodule[sigA,sigB]
```

In my case, I also want to have predicates about these signatures that might change in the different instantiations of my module. Something like, say,

```
module mymodule[sigA,predA]
sig B extends sigA {}
pred B[b : B] { ... }

fact { all b : B | predA[b] => predB[b]}
```

If I just do it like this naively, Alloy complains that it won't typecheck, as parameters to a module are automatically assumed to be signatures. Is there any workaround or some other way to make modules be polymorphic in predicates like this?

Answer (score 0):

Genericity in the module system is indeed limited to signatures parameters. The only workaround (sort of) I know of is exemplified in `util/graph` for instance, of which I'm pasting an excerpt:

```
module util/graph[node]
/** graph is rooted at root */
pred rootedAt[r: node->node, root: node] {
  node in root.*r
}
```

As you can see, `node` is a parameter. If you want to talk about a relation on `node`s, then you pass it as a parameter (e.g.: `rootedAt`). So, you can;t require the existence of a relation on `node`s, in addition to the signature `node` itself, but you can give the module "client" means to reason about fields too.